# Flex RSL Error: the loaded file did not have a valid signature

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash, rsl

I'm using Flex SDK 4.5 to create swf files, recently I got the following error when try to open my swf file:

> [trace] Warning: Ignoring 'secure' attribute in policy file from http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml.  The 'secure' attribute is only permitted in HTTPS and socket policy files.  See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files for details.
>   [trace] Error #2046: The loaded file did not have a valid signature.
>   [trace] Failed to load RSL http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.5.1.21328/framework_4.5.1.21328.swz
>   [trace] Failing over to RSL framework_4.5.1.21328.swz

I totally have no idea whats going on with rsl loading step.

Any idea how to solve this without have to statically linking rsl into swf file ?

Answer (score 2):

Please check your mime-type setup for .swz, at least in my case trying to load signed Adobe framework SDK libraries 4.5.1 from application folder rather than from Adobe was achieved by adding mime type in Apache http.conf as follows

AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swz

Answer (score 1):

This error normally pops up because the compiled application is using a different framework version than the one you're trying to load through RSLs.  Flash Player verifies the filesize digest of the RSLs before being loaded because if a different framework is being loaded in than the one specified by the application, it can cause erratic behavior.

I would imagine you're trying to do this through Flash Builder.  If that's the case, you should download the flex sdk of the same version number and build on that for it to work.  If not, you'll have to make sure the RSL points to the same version as what you're compiling with.

Comment: That is also what thought, but I already couble check the IntelliJ Idea setting, I use only one flex SDK 4.5, and no other flex SDK around (at the same computer). I compile the flex application with flex SDK 4.5 selected, but still no luck. The flex application still complaining about invalid signature.

Comment: Be warned, there is a Flex SDK 4.5.0 and a 4.5.1.  Make sure you have the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of this problem can be when the clock on the user's computer is set to the wrong time/date.

I know this sounds weird, but it has something to do with how the signatures on the swz files are interpreted.

This was the solution for one of our customers.